# error C2070 - extern array size not specified. - array passed to MACRO

Tags: c++, macros, extern

I understand that the size of a incomplete object cannot be determined by the compiler and hence the MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE fails. MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE performs a sizeof operation.

1. What can I do to have this working. One way would be for me to specify the size of A_array[3] in A.h. 
   But the problem is someone can be modifying A.cpp and not make the update to the index in A.h
2. Can the size of A_array be passed (not exactly) on to the MACRO (somehow like variable argument macro) and then MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE will use that info and maintain it's current functionality.
   I have very little experience with MACROs and help on this front for this problem would be great.

How can I modify the MACRO and class defined in make_array.h to MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE?

```
A.h
----------------------
#ifndef INC_A_H
#define INC_A_H
#include "make_array.h"

extern const int A_array[];
extern const int_array_range my_array;  
#endif
----------------------

A.cpp
----------------------
#include "make_array.h"
#include "A.h"
const int A_array[] = {10, 20, 30};
----------------------

B.cpp
----------------------
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "make_array.h"

int main()
{
    const int_array_range my_array = MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE(A_array);

    const int *curr = my_array.first; // Accessing std::pair first

    const int *last = my_array.second; // Accessing std::pair second 

    for(curr; curr!=last; curr++)
    {
        std::cout << *curr << "\n";
    }

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
----------------------

make_array.h
----------------------
#ifndef INC_MAKE_ARRAY_H
#define INC_MAKE_ARRAY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#define ARRAY_SIZE( my_array ) (sizeof(my_array)/sizeof((my_array)[0]))

template< typename Array_Entry>
class ARRAY_RANGE : public std::pair<Array_Entry*,Array_Entry*>
{
    public:
    ARRAY_RANGE() : std::pair<Array_Entry*,Array_Entry*>( 0, 0 ) {}
    ARRAY_RANGE( Array_Entry *start, Array_Entry *end ) : std::pair<Array_Entry*,Array_Entry*>( start, end ) {}
};

template< typename Array_Entry>
ARRAY_RANGE<Array_Entry> make_array_range( Array_Entry *start, Array_Entry *end )
{
    return ARRAY_RANGE<Array_Entry>( start, end );
}

#define MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE( my_array )\
make_array_range( (my_array)+0, (my_array) + ARRAY_SIZE( my_array ) )

typedef ARRAY_RANGE<const int> int_array_range;

#endif
```

Output:

```
1>projects\test_extern\test_extern\b.cpp(7): error C2070: 'const int []': illegal sizeof operand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a

```
extern const size_t A_array_size;
```

to A.h and

```
const size_t A_array_size = sizeof(A_array);
```

to A.cpp and then use `A_array_size` in your `MAKE_ARRAY_RANGE`-macro. E.g. like this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE( my_array ) (my_array ## _size) / sizeof((my_array)[0]))
```

While this solves your problem described above, I doubt that this will solve your real problem. Can't you use `std::list` `or std::vector` ?

Comment: +1 for `std::vector`. Since C++11 introduced [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) there is really no excuse not to use `std::vector`.